# I can't show a 'Wait' screen when I need to wait for a thread to be finished

Tags: multithreading, java-me

I need to show some kind of animation(progress indicator) when a task takes some time to complete.
This is the code for my wait screen:

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Gauge;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Item;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;

    public class scrWaitForm extends Form {

        public static scrWaitForm create() {
            return new scrWaitForm();
        }
        private final Gauge gagProgressBar;
        private final StringItem strMensaje;

        protected scrWaitForm() {
            super("Procesando");
            this.gagProgressBar = new Gauge("", false, Gauge.INDEFINITE, Gauge.CONTINUOUS_RUNNING);
            this.gagProgressBar.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_CENTER| Item.LAYOUT_VCENTER);
            this.append(gagProgressBar);
            this.strMensaje=new StringItem("Loading...", null);
            this.append(strMensaje);
        }
    }
```

And this is how I show it :

```
    public void showWaitForm() {
        scrWaitForm frmWaitForm = scrWaitForm.create();
        mDisplay.setCurrent(frmWaitForm);
    }
```

As you can see, it is very simple. I only use a Gauge. The problem is that the wait screen won't be displayed if I need to wait for a thread to be finished so that I can use some operation results(from the thread) in other operations. However, if I only call the wait screen without waiting for the thread to complete it works as expected.

This is what I initially did:

```
    thrLoadCustomers load = new thrLoadCustomers(rmsCustomers, url);
    Thread t = new Thread(load);
    showWaitForm()
    t.start();          
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    }
```

But then with the help of [Mister Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813951/mister-smith) I ended up using something like this :

WSResult result = new WSResult();

```
//Start thread here
new Thread(new LoadCustomersTask(result)).start();

//This is old school thread sync. 
synchronized(result){
    showWaitForm();
    while(!result.isCompleted()){
        result.wait();
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?? How do you normally show an animation or another screen so that user sees that something is taking place and don't intend to invoke the same action over and over again.

Thanks in advance.